# Migration from WiX 3 to Wix 4 (4.0.0.5918) now generating an error in Candle.exe (CNDL0200)

Tags: wix-extension, wix4

I'm a very lightweight user of WiX and could readily stay on V3 was it not for the fact that I believe it requires .net 3.5 and that seems to not to want to install on my new Win 10 development machine. So I'm looking at V4 which does not have that dependency, but is generating the following error in candle :-

> error CNDL0200 : The File element contains an unhandled extension
>   element 'PermissionEx'.  Please ensure that the extension for elements
>   in the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension' namespace has
>   been provided.

In my .wxs file I have :-

Wix xmlns='http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs' 
      xmlns:netfx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension'      xmlns:util='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension'

The command line call to candle.exe contains

> -ext WixUtilExtension

Am I missing something obvious, or are there known issues with V4 that means I should pursue getting a version 3 working on my Win 10 machine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of March 2019, WiX v4 is still under active development and is not recommended for anything but experimental use. A WiX v4 beta is expected later this summer.

Comment: OK, Thanks Rob. I've managed to revert back to V3 and that works.